# How can I define typescript typings for a javascript package's function that is called on another function that returns a function?

Tags: angular, typescript, types, leaflet, typescript-typings

I want to use the [Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup) extension in my Angular app, but it is a native JS package and I need to define typings for that.

I have to use it the following way:

`mySubGroup = L.featureGroup.subGroup(parentGroup, arrayOfMarkers);`

where featureGroup is a function from Leaflet, defined the following way in Leaflet's typings:

`export function featureGroup(layers?: Layer[]): FeatureGroup;`

So my original plan was to redefine the FeatureGroup class with a subGroup function but here comes the plot twist: the compiler says that featureGroup() is returning the following type:

`(layers?: Layer[]) => FeatureGroup`

I tried to define a type for this expression but I can't declare a function in a type's body.

The only workaround I found to be able to compile my code is to import L as any, this way I basically disable the type checking, but that's something I want to avoid.

Any help is appreciated, I have totally ran out of ideas at this point.

Comment: Could you try to include a [mcve] that one could drop into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)?  Or if not a standalone IDE, perhaps a link to a web IDE with code and the required configuration?  Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/qNBZzN) meet your needs or am I missing something?  If so, I might be able to do better if you give me more complete example code.

Comment: you can install types for the library:

`npm install --save-dev @types/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup`

Comment: Oh my god, thank you @Lambo14 !!! I had no idea that a types package exists for this one too

Answer (score 0):

There was an npm package @types/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup to solver this issue (thanks for @Lambo14 for finding it!). They use a namespace in it for the parent function:

```
    namespace featureGroup {
        /**
         * Creates a feature subgroup, optionally given an initial parent group and a set of layers.
         */
        function subGroup(parentGroup?: LayerGroup, layers?: Layer[]): FeatureGroup.SubGroup;
    }
```